# Changing keyboard to steering wheel in F1 2012

Tags: f1-2012

Recently installed F1 2012 and began using it with keyboard. Since then I've brought a Nitho Drive Pro v512 Air steering wheel but cannot get it to work with the game. The device is installed, drivers installed and I can change some of the controls under My F1 to be used by the steering wheel. However, it's almost impossible to drive (like using the keyboard before) and the vast majority of functions still require the keyboard. It's as if the game is not fully recognising the steering wheel. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

F1 2012 works on pre-defined controller maps, like most Feral games. The support for many controllers is built-in and automatically activates.

However in your case, your wheel controller is from a less-known manufacturer, so Feral does not have a keymap written into the program.

Your solution is as follows:

> Ensure your controller is connected, powered, and that all drivers are functioning. Launch **F1 2012**. From the main menu, navigate to **My F1** and select **Driving Controls**. Now set the control profile to **Custom** by clicking on it. Set Override Input Device to **Steering Wheel** and click **View/Customise Profile**. You can now manually map the controls to your wheel by clicking on the command (eg: Turn Left) and then moving the control surface on your wheel (eg: Moving the wheel left).

If that doesn't help, it means your controller is unsupported as a native wheel by F1 2012, so try this:

> Download [XPadder](http://xpadder.com) and install it. In the XPadder interface, map your wheel control surfaces to the normal keyboard controls used in F1, eg: map 'Pressing the accelerator' to 'UP arrow'. Once you have completed this for the entire keymap, start up F1 2012 and in My F1 set the control profile to Keyboard. Essentially, while playing, your input goes from your wheel to XPadder, which translates it into a simple key-command for F1 to interpret. (Wheel > XPadder > F1 2012)

I hope this solves your problem :)